# Which hash functions allow generating message using length and hash-value?

Tags: algorithm, hash

Assume the `length` of message and its `hash` are known.

Are there any hash functions that would allow generating the message back?

Computationally heavy implementations are OK, however, I am looking for a variety of such reversible hash functions, that would take second/minute/hour/day/month for a typical message of size less than 1KB.

Probably, this is not even a hash function, actually, any function that takes message and produces fixed-length (less than 1KB) result are OK.

The major request is that hash.length is constant and is way less than message.length.

Comment: If message can be retrieved from a "hash", then it's not a hash :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Just understood that. However, still looking for functions that would allow such reversal.

Comment: Then you're looking for a regular encryption/decryption. Properly-executed crypto is unbreakable.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev maybe -- looking for functions, breakable in well-known time: second/minute/hour/day/month...

Comment: "hash.length is constant and is way less than message.length" - if it's a lossy conversion (like in a hash function), then source message retrieval is theoretically impossible. Content is lost, where do you imagine to get it from? In a lossless conversion, encrypted message size will be roughly equal to source text size.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev don't forget that we have `message.length`, and also, could probably assume its english text (or maybe other language).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev like -- for given size and hash, there might be only one message that contains a human-understandable english phrase.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I don't argue that there might be more than one... But what if there is an approach that works pretty well with variable message length but constant hash size?

Comment: This all sounds very brute-forcey. Certainly not a minute-hour range, for whatever function/algo you choose, I think. And if you are bruteforcing, then the algo doesn't matter (much)

Comment: Sounds like "compression" ...